# "Password can't be blank" displayed twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to validate a user's password on `create` and `update` (custom authentication, no gems). A password should ALWAYS be required on `create`, but only required on `update` if they type something in.

**models/user.rb**

```
has_secure_password
validates :password, presence: {if: :requires_password?}, length: {minimum: 6}
validates :password_confirmation, presence: {if: :requires_password?}

private
  def requires_password?
    new_record? || !password.nil?
  end
```

This works as expected, but when creating a new user, the error message "Password can't be blank" is displayed twice.

Is there a simple fix for this, or am I approaching password validation the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me!

```
validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_blank: true
```

It requires a password on create, but only updates if something is passed in. And because I'm using `has_secure_password`, the confirmation is handled automatically.

Updated **models/user.rb**

```
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_blank: true
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10):

See the [doc of `has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password), validation of presence is already included:

> Validations for presence of password, confirmation of password (using
>   a "password_confirmation" attribute) are automatically added. You can
>   add more validations by hand if need be.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
validates :password, \
  presence: true,
  length: {minimum: 6},
  confirmation: true,
  if: :requires_password?
```

(I broke it up into multiple lines for legibility; you can still use the one-liner)

You don't need two separate validations - you just need one on `password` that includes the confirmation validation.